# Sorting a hashmap first with values then keys in java

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

Hello guys i have a hash map like **a:1,c:2,d:3,b:2** and i want to sort it like **d:3,b:2,c:2,a:1, descending in values and alphabetical order in keys** how can i do it i would be grateful for any help thanks!

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Hey Dante, welcome ! Have you tried something already? It would be nice to start with something existing to help you further

Comment: I reopened because the supposed duplicate is about simple sorting of a map. This question is more complex, asking to sort first by values and then by keys.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the following in descending order of values then keys.  I amended the list to make it more interesting.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of("a", 8, "b", 2, "c", 4, "d",
                8, "e", 3, "f", 4, "g", 7, "h", 1, "i", 5, "j", 2);
```

First define a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to use in sorting the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) entries. Each entry is represented by the [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) class. That class offers methods [`comparingByValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue()) and [`comparingByKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByKey()).

The following code says, first sort by `value`, then by the `key`.  These are sorted in natural order except the following `reversed()` method says reverse the sorting of all comparators prior.  So the `values` will be sorted in reversed order and the `keys` in alphabetical order.

```java
Comparator<Entry<String, Integer>> comp = Entry
        .<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
        .thenComparing(Entry.comparingByKey());
```

This streams the existing map's entrys and applies the comparator to the sort method. It then collects them in a linked hashMap to preserve the order. The merge function does not play a part in this but is syntactically required.

```java
Map<String, Integer> lhmap =
        map.entrySet().stream().sorted(comp)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                        Entry::getValue,
                        (a, b) -> a,      // merge function
                        LinkedHashMap::new));

lhmap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

That code prints:

```
a=8
d=8
g=7
i=5
c=4
f=4
e=3
b=2
j=2
h=1
```

Comment: I think you misread the Question, as I had done. The Question asks for sorting by *values* primarily, and sort by *keys* secondarily. The values may coincidentally be equal (be multiple), so sorting by keys secondarily does indeed make sense.

Comment: You're right. Time to adjust.  And thanks!!

Comment: I have figured it out thanks to WJS with a comparator like `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> firstwithvaluessecoundwiththekeys = Map.Entry
                .<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed() 
                .thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey());` I have solved my question thanks everyone again!

Answer (score 0):

A [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is not necessarily ordered, and in fact does not guarantee that the key value pair orders wil lremain constant over time. From the docs:

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

If you want a sorted map, use a [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) or `SortedMap`. There are a few options. [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is probably the simplest.

> A Red-Black tree based NavigableMap implementation. The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

So to create a map with the keys in descending alphabetical order something like this should do the tick:

```java
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {      
        return o2.compareTo(o1);
    }
};

TreeMap<String, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
```

Comment: How does this address the Question? The Question asks about sorting by values first, and then by keys secondarily.

Comment: OP asks how to sort a `HashMap`, so I gave them a simple example of creating a sorted map. I read the "descending in values and alphabetical order in keys" section as a description of the map in part because sorting on keys, and then values does not make much sense given that keys in a `HashMap` are unique and sorting matching keys on value is a non-issue. That could be  misinterpretation on my part. I appreciate you additions to my answer, they were definitely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is using java 8 streams.

//LinkedHashMap preserve the ordering of elements in which they are inserted

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> reverseSortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    unSortedMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .forEachOrdered(x -> reverseSortedMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()));
     
    System.out.println("Reverse Sorted Map   : " + reverseSortedMap);
```